# Python: I can't get more than 65885 bytes from stdin

Tags: python, python-3.x, stdout, stdin, macos-catalina

I have a Python script that I use to get data from stdin, like this:

```
$ cat requests.txt | ./script.py
```

It's working good, BUT when I have more than 65885 bytes in `requests.txt` then the script only gets those bytes. I'm getting the stdin like this:

```
import sys
from queue import Queue


def to_queue():
    '''Read the pipe in and store lines as queue elements'''
    q = Queue()
    for line in sys.stdin:
        print(line)
        q.put(line)
    return q
```

That `print(line)` shows me by stdout that the data I've got was incomplete.

I'm using Python 3.7 on Mac OS Catalina.

Any idea how can I solve it? Maybe increasing the stdin buffer? 
Thanks in advance.

UPDATE:
I'm testing it in MacOC Catalina, and not in Ubuntu.

I see and do something like this:

`gen_requests.sh > requests.txt`

Then:

`cat requests.txt | python script.py` --> it works, it show all the content

`gen_requests.sh | python script.py` --> it fail, it only shows until 65585 bytes

How can be this possible??

Comment: How are you determining that you are only getting at most 65,885 bytes?

Comment: Hmmmm not sure if it is the buffering. You could try using `sys.stdin.buffer.raw` to see if that is the case. But this seems like something else is going on, are you sure you are diagnosing this corrrectly?

Comment: As an aside, do you really need a `queue.Queue`? Because that is sort of a special-case synchronized version, otherwise, you might just want a `collections.deque`

Comment: Cannot reproduce. I created a file of size 1588890 and your code (once I added a call to to_queue) worked.

Comment: @chepner I know it because I've copy from the console all the output of that print() and, after paste that into a editor the total chars are 65885. May be with another content in request.txt it is a little different but it'll be arround that number.

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga yes, i need queue.Queue because it is part of a bug code that use that in that format.

Comment: Thanks @juanpa.arrivillaga, I've tried with sys.stdin.buffer.raw but I don't see any extrange char there. As you said it looks like another problem.

Comment: I've tried using this function from a simple main and it works ok. I'll add some details I've seen testing this.

Comment: @tdelaney thanks, now I agree with you. I've added an Update.

Comment: You aren't by chance using some old editor version that can only edit files that are 64K or less.  You don't mention your OS, but you might redirect the output to a file and see what the file's size is instead.

Comment: I'm using the console directly. My OS is MacOS Catalina 10.15.4. The file has 145576 bytes. When I do `cat requests.txt | wc -c` I see it.

Comment: Regarding I see, after several tests, it isn't a Python issue, it is something related with MacOS console, its stdin or whit "Oh my zsh" shell, I don't be sure, but not with Python. Then, should I delete this question and open a new one? Thanks.

Comment: Sounds like `gen_requests.sh` behaves differently when it is writing output to a pipe than when it is writing to a regular file.